# Invalid location tag (form)

Tags: java, html, jsp

So I am querying my DB to get the following out of it and display it on my html, to the left I would like to have an update button and a delete button for easy deletion and updating of current information, however I continue to get the error invalid location tag (from);

```
  <tr>
       <td><%=rs.getInt("id") %></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Year") %></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Make") %></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Model") %></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Color") %></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Availability") %></td>
       <td><form action="update-post" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" name="update" value={{id}}>Update</button>
            </form></td>
        <td><form action="deletecar" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" name="delete" value={{id}}>Delete</button>
             </form></td>

         </tr>
```

This has me asking 2 questions how do I select the id as given of each table to delete it from and, how do I fix this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <tr>
   <td><%=rs.getInt("id") %></td>
   <td><%=rs.getString("Year") %></td>
   <td><%=rs.getString("Make") %></td>
   <td><%=rs.getString("Model") %></td>
   <td><%=rs.getString("Color") %></td>
   <td><%=rs.getString("Availability") %></td>
   <td><form action="update-post?id=<%=rs.getInt("id")%>" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
        </form></td>
    <td><form action="deletecar?id=<%=rs.getInt("id")%>" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
         </form></td>

     </tr>
```

After some fiddeling this seems to work form me.